# NuSoap array of arrays of strings

Tags: c#, php, wsdl, nusoap

I have been trying for the last day to return a valid response that can be deserialized by a c# soap client.

The only problem is when the webservice is returning an array of arrays of strings.

The error that the C# client gets is :

```
The specified type was not recognized: name='errorArray',  namespace='urn:https://xxxxxxxx/index.php', at <errors xmlns=''>.
```

I am using PHP Nusoap to generate the WSDL.

This is the registered function ( I am skipping some parts since the error i am getting is only related to the "errors" structure):

```
$server->register(
            'createEntity',                                     
            array('requests' => 'tns:inputCreateEntity'),       
            array(
                    'return' => 'tns:returnCreateEntity',
                    'errors' => 'tns:createEntityErrorArray'
            ),                                                  
            'urn:'.$nameSpace,                                  
            'urn:'.$nameSpace.'#createEntity'                   

    );

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
            'createEntityErrorArray',
            'complexType',
            'array',
            'all',
            'SOAP-ENC:Array',
            array(),
            array(array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:errorArray[]')),
            'tns:errorArray'
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'errorArray',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    'all',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')),
    'xsd:string');
```

This is the XML error part that my soap server is returning

```
 <errors xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:errorArray[1]">
        <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]">
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">GENERAL ERRORS :</item>
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">The request array must contain at least a valid array!</item>
        </item>
     </errors>
```